# How to search for Account records by currency in SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

In SuiteScript v1, how can I search for Account records by currency?

Or at least get a list of Account records containing their internalid and currency, which I can then filter myself.

I'm asking because I can't see currency as a search filter or a search column at http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_1/script/record/account.html.

I tried anyway to use it as a filter and got: An nlobjSearchFilter contains invalid search criteria: currency.

```
var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord(
    'account',
    null,
    [ new nlobjSearchFilter('currency', null, 'is', 12345, null) ],
    [ new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid') ]
);
```

And when I try to use it as a column I get: An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax: currency.

```
var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord(
    'account',
    null,
    [],
    [ new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid'), new nlobjSearchColumn('currency')  ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround you can try is using formula in search column. Try your search using 'formulacurrency'

[ 'formulacurrency: {currency}','is',12345 ]